# C# & VSCode - OmniSharp not working for multi project workspace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

VSC is acting a bit weird and I can't figure out how to fix it.
I am doing a tutorial and currently, I have multiple files with the same code. What I can't understand is why one of the files is showing "Problemns" and is highlithing them in the code and the other one doesn't.

Also in the 2nd file, even the breadcrumbs are missing.

1st file

[image]

2nd file

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question *as text*, not as images.

Comment: You have nullable references enabled, that's why.

Comment: nullable reference is enabled in both cases. I don't think it's a c# error....seems more of a Visual Studio Code thing.

Comment: It probably is a VS Code thing, which I've never used, but unless you want to dig deep into whether it's an IDE bug and report it, I'd just go on with my coding.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so it seems that this is due to the fact that at this moment OmniSharp does not Multi Project support. Each time you want autocomplete and error reporting in a folder from your workspace you need to manually change your OmniSharp folder from here:
[image]